# Android 9-patch and drawable-mdpi

Tags: android, drawable, nine-patch

I created a simple 9-patch image for Android. Poured into a folder drawable-mpdi. Everything works, but the upper frame is lost. It is not clear why. See screenshot:

[image]

This is my 9-patch file:

[image]

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/30086473/input_login_active2.9.png

My XML layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/login_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/auth_logo"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="273dip"
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/auth_edit_text"
                android:hint="@string/auth_login"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="273dip"
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/auth_edit_text_left"
                android:hint="@string/auth_login_left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="17dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem? How to recycle 9-patch, that there was a blue frame at the upper of element?

There is @drawable/auth_edit_text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t" />
</selector>
```

Comment: I don't see where your layout references `drawable/input_login_active2`. Is it coming in from `drawable/login_bg`? If so, please post the xml for that.

Comment: Yes. I add @drawable/auth_edit_text in text of question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pixel borders seem to be incorrect (reversed maybe). Try this instead:

[image]

With your original, you'd be stretching the phone icon as well, not just the bubble. Also, you had the content area and stretch area reversed for the top and bottom (I've inverted them in the attachment). While I don't know that that would specifically cause the problem you've shown, I would give it a try and see what happens.

**EDIT**: Try this:

[image]

**EDITED ANSWER FROM COMMENTS**: I think that may be your issue is that it's looking for the ldpi image, not finding one, and falling back to the default and scaling it down. Since the border is only 1 px, it simply disappears when scaled down.

Comment: Yes, I agree that your version is better, but it does not solved the problem( I tried right now - I see the same result. I am in complete disarray - the only problem in that the screen resolution, as we have the screenshot. On hdpi, xhdpi all is ok! There are any variants?

Comment: I have an idea: Try making the textbox 2 lines long, and see if the problem still exists. If it works with 2 lines, I think I know the issue.

Comment: Yes, if there is 2 lines in textbox - problem is exist too. And 3, 4 and other count of lines - problem still exist.

Comment: And if there is 2 lines - bottom frame is lost too

Comment: That is odd. You're sure the device is mdpi? Also, I noticed you typed `drawable-mpdi` as the folder you put it in -- I'm sure that's just a typo, but make sure it's `drawable-mdpi` because it looks like you have some unexpected scaling going on. I'll edit in another version I think you should try.

Comment: Yes, this is just a typo (drawable-mpdi :)
I don't sure that my device is mdpi... If my device is ldpi, you think that I must create a new version with less size?

Comment: Yes, I'd do that or just use the smaller one I edited in, putting it in a `drawable-ldpi` folder. I think that may be your issue is that it's looking for the ldpi image, not finding one, and falling back to the default and scaling it down. Since the border is only 1 px, it simply disappears when scaled down.

Comment: I will add a new screen in question. one minute

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it. :) I edited the comment into the answer for anyone else who may run into this.

Comment: I wonder about the explanation about losing the border. The aapt strips the 1-pixel border from 9-patches and places the info into an extension chunk of a plain .png file that then goes into the .pak. That extension chunk is not subject to scaling in the same way as the image, so the fact that it's scaled from mdpi to lpdi should not make the stretch or padding extents disappear. Perhaps in creating the ldpi drawable a different issue with the graphic was inadvertently fixed.

Comment: @TedHopp: In the mdpi to ldpi scaling, it's scaling independently of the 9-patch implementation. You can tell just by looking at the corners in his screenshot -- there are aliasing artifacts and the corner has not retained its roundness.

Comment: I realize that the image is being scaled from mdpi to ldpi. My point is that the scaling (which happens at run time) cannot cause the 9-patch borders to disappear; the borders were removed from the image at build time.

Comment: He's not talking about the 9-patch borders though, he's talking about the 1px blue stroke along the top of the bubble. It's subtle, but it's definitely missing in the screenshot.

Comment: Okay--I finally get what you're saying. I misread your explanation and was being dense about it. Sorry about that and thanks for the patience.

Comment: It's all good. :) Like I said, it's very subtle and the question easy to misread.

Comment: @kcoppock: I have another small question for you) How do you make a smaller version of the background, but without losing quality? I just tried to reduce the image in Photoshop, but it lost color and much more...

Comment: @Anton: Depends how you designed it initially. For my example, I just used Content-Aware Scaling (Photoshop CS5.5), but all of your effects could easily be done with a shape layer and layer styles, which would then be resizable without any quality loss.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know before about this wonderfull function!